# Binding dojo date picker and dojo time picker to one NotesDateTime field?

Tags: xpages

Is there anyway to bind the values from separate dojo date picker and dojo time picker into one NotesDateTime field?  I want to be able to take the values returned from the two controls and combine them into on filed but also take a NotesDateTime value, break it apart and display the values in the separate dojo date and time components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I decided to do this:

```
var dateStart = getComponent("djDateTextBox1").getValue();
var timeStart = getComponent("djTimeTextBox1").getValue();


if (dateStart != null && timeStart != null)
{
    var dt =   @Date(@Year(dateStart),@Month(dateStart),@Day(dateStart),@Hour(timeStart),@Minute(timeStart),@Second(timeStart));        
      docContractor.replaceItemValue("ContractorStartDateTime",session.createDateTime(dt));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question. Use two separate fields for the date and time and a computed one for a combined version.

Comment: I was hoping there was a more elegant way.  Otherwise, I wind up with 3 fields on the notes document which could have confusion later. 1. A field with the picked date and 12PM default time. 2. The picked time and the default of a current date.  3. A field with the combined date and time values.

Comment: Why do you need to add them to the document? Just add the combined one if that is all you want to save. Remember you do not need to have corresponding fields for every data item on the XPage.